# Running test suite from both terminal using pytest and unittest runner but show only unittest runner results and execute once

Tags: automated-testing, python, unit-tests, test-execuation

i am trying to execute my following test suite:

```
import unittest
from Login_Page import LoginPageAndLogout


def test_suite():
    # get all tests from classes
    login_test = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(LoginPageAndLogout)

    # create a test suite
    all_tests = unittest.TestSuite([
        login_test
    ])

    # run the suite
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(all_tests)
```

from Pycharm's terminal using the command :

```
sudo pytest selenium-tests/testSuite.py -vvv -s
```

and a part of the output is the following:

```
============================================================================================================ test session starts ============================================================================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.14, pytest-3.1.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0 -- /usr/bin/python
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /home/osboxes/PycharmProjects/WebTesting, inifile:
plugins: cov-2.5.1
collected 3 items 

selenium-tests/testSuite.py::LoginPageAndLogout::test_failed_login <- selenium-tests/Login_Page.py PASSED
selenium-tests/testSuite.py::LoginPageAndLogout::test_login <- selenium-tests/Login_Page.py FAILED
selenium-tests/testSuite.py::test_suite test_failed_login (Login_Page.LoginPageAndLogout) ... ok
test_login (Login_Page.LoginPageAndLogout) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 55.993s
```

The structure of my `Login_Page.py` file is:

```
class LoginPageAndLogout(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # ...

    # login with incorrect credentials to get error message
    def test_failed_login(self):
        # ...

    # login with correct credentials
    def test_login(self):
        # ...

    def tearDown(self):
        # ...
```

As you can see from the output, I have 2 tests but the terminal collects three things instead and run each test twice. Is there a way to execute only the `PASSED/FAILED` execution, not the `... ok` ?

If I comment out `unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(all_tests)` my tests executed only once but I get the `... ok` result instead of the `PASSED/FAILED` which is the one I want; so I see the `pytest` execution results instead of the unittests runner results.

How can I run from the terminal my suite using the unitest runner only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was quite easy as I had just misunderstood how my unit test was being executed all this time.

The only thing I had to do was to comment out the whole `test_suite` class from my `testSuite.py` file and just import at the top of this file the classes from the test scripts i wanted to execute.

Now my tests run only once and I can still execute all my scripts all at once without typing them in my command one by one using the exact same command:
`sudo pytest selenium-tests/testSuite.py -vvv -s`

The output of that command is now:

```
osboxes@osboxes:~/PycharmProjects/WebTesting$ sudo pytest selenium-tests/testSuite.py -vvv -s
========================================================================================================================= test session starts ==========================================================================================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.14, pytest-3.1.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0 -- /usr/bin/python
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /home/osboxes/PycharmProjects/WebTesting, inifile:
plugins: cov-2.5.1
collected 2 items 

selenium-tests/testSuite.py::LoginPageAndLogout::test_failed_login <- selenium-tests/Login_Page.py PASSED
selenium-tests/testSuite.py::LoginPageAndLogout::test_login <- selenium-tests/Login_Page.py PASSED

====================================================================================================================== 2 passed in 58.81 seconds =======================================================================================================================
osboxes@osboxes:~/PycharmProjects/WebTesting$
```